# can you help me with this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to know what is the error from my function because when i change the select an option on my filter button it does not work can you help me this is my code.

```js
$("#date_employed").on("change", function() {

  var selected = this.value;

  if (selected != "All") {
    rows.filter("[name=" + selected + "]").show();
    rows.not("[name=" + selected + "]").hide();
    var visibleRows = rows.filter("[name=" + selected + "]");
  } else {
    rows.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>
<select id="date_employed" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="choose">Filter</option>
    <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
    <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you can mention the error.

Answer (score 0):

The < / script was missing > and you had }); to many:

```
<script>
$("#date_employed").on("change", function(){
  var selected = this.value;

    if(selected != "All"){
        rows.filter("[name="+selected+"]").show();
        rows.not("[name="+selected+"]").hide();
        var visibleRows = rows.filter("[name="+selected+"]");
    }
    else {
        rows.show();
    }
});  
</script>                                                                                                                       
<button type="button" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>
<select id="date_employed" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle">
  <option value="choose">Filter</option>
  <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
  <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
</select>
```

And you can also do:

```
var selected = $(this).val();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer bob.. but still doesn't work :(

Comment: rows is undefined (are we missing some code?)
And your if statement will always be true (since your variable selected is never "All")